# php reformat nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a stored **unlimited** nested levels array with unwanted extra data.

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'item1',
        'level' => 0,
        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
        'children' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item1',
            'level' => 1,
            'extra_key' => 'some_data',
            'children' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item1',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item1',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'item2',
        'level' => 0,
        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
        'children' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item2',
            'level' => 2,
            'extra_key' => 'some_data',
            'children' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item2',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item2',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'item3',
        'level' => 0,
        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
        'children' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item3',
            'level' => 1,
            'extra_key' => 'some_data',
            'children' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item3',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item3',
                'level' => 2,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Expected output array:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'item1',
        'nodes' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item1',
            'nodes' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item1',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item1',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'item2',
        'nodes' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item2',
            'nodes' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item2',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item2',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'item3',
        'nodes' => array(
            'name' => 'sub-item3',
            'nodes' => array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub-item3',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-sub2-item3',
                'nodes' => array()
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

I want to remove unwanted keys like `level` , `extra_key` from all levels and i want also to change the name of the key `children` to `nodes` then reproduce the same array with the **same structure** with the new format.

How can i achieve that?

I tried to do it by recursive function but i failed to reproduce the same structrue

Comment: array_walk_recursive  read about this on php.net

Comment: Can you show us what would be the array you would expect as output?

Comment: @zsram I edited the question to add the expected output array

Comment: Changing the key name recursively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808602/recursively-replace-keys-in-an-array  .

As for removing the keys, use unset($arr['level']); as you are looping though $arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure doesn't make sense, probably because of that you was unable to write recursive function. If it is possible to change structure, I would suggest this one (with reformat function implementation):

```
<?php

$actual = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'item1',
        'level' => 0,
        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-item1',
                'level' => 1,
                'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'sub-sub-item1',
                        'level' => 2,
                        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                        'children' => array()
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'sub-sub2-item1',
                        'level' => 2,
                        'extra_key' => 'some_data',
                        'children' => array()
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
);

$expected = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'item1',
        'nodes' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'sub-item1',
                'nodes' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'sub-sub-item1',
                        'nodes' => array()
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'sub-sub2-item1',
                        'nodes' => array()
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
);

function change_array($original)
{
    return array_map('change_node', $original);
}

function change_node($node)
{
    return [
        'name' => $node['name'],
        'nodes' => array_map('change_node', $node['children']),
    ];
}

var_dump($expected === change_array($actual));
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will do what you want recursively.
You can add extra excluded and/or renamed indices if required;

```
function parseArray($array): array
{
    // The resulting array
    $result          = [];
    // Indices you want renamed [`from` => `to`]
    $renameIndices   = ['children' => 'nodes'];
    // Indices you want excluded [`1`, `2`]
    $excludedIndices = ['level', 'extra_key'];
    foreach ($array as $idx => $content)
    {
        // If excluded, continue (skip) node.
        if (in_array($idx, $excludedIndices, true))
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Setting the resulting (new) index.
        $resultIdx = $idx;
        // Check if this index should be renamed
        if (array_key_exists($idx, $renameIndices))
        {
            // If index should be renamed, apply new name
            $resultIdx = $renameIndices[$idx];
        }
        // If this content block is an array. Parse it.
        if (is_array($content))
        {
            $content = parseArray($content);
        }
        // Save content to resulting array.
        $result[$resultIdx] = $content;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,
Please take a look in @Anton Serdyuk repy here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41364381/1344637